# Linux shell scripting - Getting the sum of numbers within a String but also keeping the String with the sum number

Tags: linux, string, shell

I have an xml file that has numbers within tags. 
Ex)

```
<REC_CNT>25000</REC_CNT>
<REC_CNT>25000</REC_CNT>
<REC_CNT>25000</REC_CNT>
<REC_CNT>11767</REC_CNT>
```

I need to get the sum of these numbers while at the same time the final output has to still have the tags around it.

```
<REC_CNT>86767</REC_CNT>
```

I've used awk already to remove the tags and add the numbers but that is not what I'm looking for. What I'm doing is a replace and if I only get the number then the replace will also replace every other number in that file that it is equal to, not just the REC_CNT... any input?

Comment: need to see your code. Good luck.

Comment: Shell is, quite simply the wrong tool for this.   Could you explain why you don't want to consider alternative languages (such as Perl or Python)?

Comment: newcount=`cat $pocfiles | grep '<REC_CNT>' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="<REC_CNT>"} {print substr($2,0)}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="<"} {print substr($1,0)}' | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}'`

I ended up removing the tags, added the numbers, and reformatted my sed statement to only replace the first instance of the number:
sed -i "0,/$oldcount/s//$newcount/"

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

`awk -v FPAT='([A-Z_]+)|([0-9]+)' '{ sum += $2; fname = $1 } END { print "<" fname ">" sum "</" fname ">" }'`

This assumes that your tags are uppercase letters or underscores. Adjust the regular expression as appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the good effort in that reply.. what i ended up doing was just taking out the tags and then reformatting my sed to only replace the specific instance i want. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an actual XML processor instead of some regular-expression based text munging tool.